# Get IP of wifi gateway?

Tags: networking, wifi

After manually connecting my wifi interface to an access point with:

```
iwconfig $wifi essid "$1"
dhclient $wifi
# ... $wifi = wlan3
```

I'm finding that I need to run:

```
route add default gw 192.168.12.1 $wifi
```

To actually get it working. I happen to know that `192.168.12.1` is the IP of the access point here, but I need a programmatic way of determining that once connected.

The closest I've found is running `route -n` which includes the line:

```
...
192.168.12.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan3
```

I've been told that given `192.168.12.0` here I can't automatically assume `192.168.12.1`, that the last number could possibly be different.

Does anyone know a programmatic way I can get `192.168.12.1` here?

---

**Update:** I found a file called `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan3.leases`. When I `grep` the access point IP I see it listed several times. I'm still not sure what option would be the best to parse.

Results of `cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan3.leases | grep 192.168.12.1`:

```
  fixed-address 192.168.12.120;
  option routers 192.168.12.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.12.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.12.1;
  fixed-address 192.168.12.120;
  option routers 192.168.12.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.12.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.12.1;
```

---

**Update #2:** Using another device where I have never run `route add ...` but have run the first command listed. I find that the dhclient lease file doesn't exist. Maybe it was the `route` command that created this file?

Comment: Doesn't `route -n` give the IP address of the gateway with a line similar to: `0.0.0.0         192.168.12.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0` as you want to route the traffic to your gateway

Comment: @fcbsd `route -n` shows the subnet `192.168.12.0` but it doesn't give the last number in the IP needed.

Comment: I was just about to suggest `dhclient` - you want the `option routers`

Comment: @fcbsd cool feel free to post as a complete answer

Comment: Did you need to print only the gatway from the command line?

Comment: @GAD3R yes pretty much, need to get the gateway IP into a variable.

Comment: Which distro are you using - as dhclient should automatically update your default gateway. So it's a little odd that it isn't doing that.

Comment: @fcbsd it is strange on Ubuntu 14.04 but it's an embedded device and not all the package versions seem to be standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command to print the gatway:

```
ip route show | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

or

```
netstat -n -r | awk '/UG/ { print $2 }'
```

or

```
netstat -n -r | grep 'UG\|*wlan3$' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: thanks this is almost right except as is it returns the gateway for my Ethernet which is different. Though I do see the IP I need when I run `ip route show` https://pastebin.com/UFV4n3qY

Comment: Here is the command I have working based on your answer. Hopefully the parsing will work consistently `ip route show | grep $wifi | awk '{ print $9 }'`

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
grep routers /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases |sort -u |cut -d ' ' -f 5 |sed -e 's/;//'
```

will generate the needed IP.

`sort -u` gives a list of unique lines like `option routers 192.168.25.1;`

`cut -d ' ' -f 5` splits the line by spaces and gives you field 5 which is `192.168.25.1` 
and then the `sed -e 's/;//'` removes the trailing semi-colon.

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon. I updated my question with a second update. Finding that the file mentioned doesn't seem to exist on devices before the `route` command is run.

Comment: if you run `/sbin/dhclient` it should do the networking magic for you